# Error on configuration of JNDI lookup for WebLogic + Spring

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, jndi

I'm migrating an application from OC4J to WebLogic 12c and the Spring beans are giving an error I can't figure out how to solve. My question is what can be the cause of this error.
I have the following bean for the JNDI lookup:

```xml
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="${datasource.jndiname}" />
    <property name="lookupOnStartup">
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property name="proxyInterface">
        <value>javax.sql.DataSource</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The value `${datasource.jndiname}` is expected to come from a `config.properties` file with the following line:

```xml
server.database.datasource=${datasource.jndiname}
```

And the value of `server.database.datasource` comes from a `config.filter` file with the line:

```xml
server.database.datasource=jdbc/DATASOURCE
```

This works fine with OC4J and it also works when I replace the `${datasource.jndiname}` to its value `jdbc/DATASOURCE` in WebLogic, but it gives me the following error if I keep the reference (and I need to keep it):

```
JndiObjectTargetSource failed to obtain new target object; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup '${datasource.jndiname}' didn't find subcontext '${datasource'. Resolved ''; remaining name '${datasource/jndiname}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found a property for the bean that fixed the error. Setting the property `resourceRef` to `false` makes the reference `${datasource.jndiname}` work as expected.
In the final code shown below I also added a `JndiTemplate`.

```xml
<bean id="dsJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">t3://localhost:7001</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="${datasource.jndiname}" />
    <property name="resourceRef" value="false"/>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
    <property name="jndiTemplate">
        <ref local="dsJndiTemplate" />
    </property>
</bean>
```